# Phytophagous worm identification

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, flowers

These worms appear soon after the [rain lilies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zephyranthes) flower and slowly nibble on the leaves growing big and chubby. They are about 5cm long, have many small red legs underneath, have no spines or spikes, and are soft-bodied.
They leave tiny green balls of excreta. I have never seen them metamorphose. [image: Here's a medium sized one on my patio] I live in Andhra Pradesh in India. Can anyone tell what species they are? Are they dangerous?

Comment: I think it's a caterpillar (an insect), not a worm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have an **Indian Lily Moth** (of the genus Polytela). It is considered a minor pest. Their habitat seems to only be around India and its surrounding area.

[image]

Their worm matches yours ... smooth, dark, but red patches and white spots:

[image]

If you dig in your garden, you may encounter these pupae:

[image]

And they eventually grow into these beautifully-multicoloured moths:

[image]

Here is a video showing their movements and their life cycle:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2l0oxZM_6XY

Comment: But it's quite curious that I have never seen the moths [they look absolutely stunning]perhaps the birds eat the larvae before they turn into pupae?